# Org-mode C-c a undefined

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to learn how to use org-mode using the org manual and videos from youtube. One of the things I'm learning is opening agenda view to visually sort todo tags and deadlines. Usually, the keystroke C-c a calls agenda view but for some reason, C-c a is undefined. Unless I'm typing the stroke wrong(I know that C-c a is not C-c C-a), I don't know why it's undefined.

As a workaround, I just use menu bar > org > agenda command button. Not exactly a keystroke but not convenient as I'm learning orgmode.

Comment: The key def is *not* installed by default. You have to add it yourself. Read the [activation section]( http://orgmode.org/manual/Activation.html#Activation) of the manual.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should add the following line in your .emacs file:

```
(global-set-key "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
```

And then reload the file (M-x load-file) or (M-x eval-buffer) or restart emacs.